# Select rows with duplicate values that may be in different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, mariadb, grouping

I have a table of businesses, and each business can have up to 3 phone numbers. I want to find any duplicate phone numbers, but since the phone numbers are in different columns I don't think I can make the classic `GROUP BY` query work.

Sample data:

| ID | Business_Name | phone_main | phone_mobile | phone_tollfree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John's Donuts | 555-551-5555 | 555-551-5556 | null |
| 2 | John's Bakery | 555-551-5557 | 555-551-5555 | null |
| 3 | SuperBake! | 555-300-1005 | null | 555-551-5555 |
| 4 | Grocery Fred | 555-223-5511 | 555-334-5555 | null |

In this case I want to identify records 1, 2, and 3 as being the same.  Simply identifying the phone number 555-551-5555 as a number with duplicates would be fine, as I can do a subquery or the calling program can use the phone number and send a new query getting all records with 555-551-5555 in any of the 3 phone columns.

This is on MariaDB if it matters.

*Edit, (adding my current flailing attempt since someone seems to *really* want it):*

Here's what I have right now:

```
SELECT ID, phone_main, phone_mobile, phone_tollfree
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM businesses b
    WHERE (
        phone IS NOT NULL AND (b.phone_mobile=phone OR b.tollfree=phone )
    )

    OR (
        phone_mobile IS NOT NULL AND (b.phone=phone_mobile OR b.phone_tollfree=phone_mobile)
    )

    OR (
        phone_tollfree IS NOT NULL AND (b.phone=phone_tollfree OR b.phone_mobile=phone_tollfree)
    ) 
) cnt


from business HAVING cnt > 1
```

Problems with this:

1. It seems to be returning every row in my table.
2. It won't find duplicates within a single column.

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: Like what? I can `group by` any single column easily. Or I can do a bunch of joins joining `phone_main` with `phone_mobile` etc, or I can try some sort of subquery, but I'm looking for strategy here, not necessarily exact code.

Comment: Take your pick.

Comment: Maybe I should have been clearer in the post, but I've been trying to figure this out ways to do this all morning. I have run `group by` queries, but they don't help because there's more than one column. I can't figure out a way to join things that will help, and my current subquery isn't returning data that makes sense. I'm posting because I am _out of ideas_.  I am _asking for help_, being told "Go on. Try something." doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about uniting all the phone columns into one an then counting the reoccurrences?

I Didn't run the code but it might give you a direction...:

```
SELECT phone, COUNT(phone)
FROM (
SELECT phone_main as phone FROM SampleData
UNION ALL

(SELECT phone_mobile as phone FROM SampleData
ORDER BY City;

UNION ALL
SELECT phone_tollfree as phone FROM SampleData
ORDER BY City; and )
)
GROUP BY phone
```

Comment: This might work too, thanks. I hadn't thought of doing a giant Union table and doing a group by on that.

Comment: This is what I'm going with for now. On my data set it is the most performant. This is the updated, tested, query:

```
SELECT phone, COUNT(phone) as count
FROM (
 (SELECT phone_main as phone FROM businesses)
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT phone_mobile as phone FROM businesses)
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT phone_tollfree as phone FROM businesses)
) as combined
WHERE phone <> ''
GROUP BY phone
HAVING count > 1
ORDER BY count desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

E.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.id <> x.id 
   AND 
     ( y.phone_main     IN(x.phone_main,x.phone_mobile,x.phone_tollfree) 
    OR y.phone_mobile   IN(x.phone_main,x.phone_mobile,x.phone_tollfree) 
    OR y.phone_tollfree IN(x.phone_main,x.phone_mobile,x.phone_tollfree) 
     );
```

Comment: This might work, thanks! I'll test it out.

Comment: So I tried this and killed the query after about 15 minutes. It looks like it'll work if I let it finish, but I can get close enough with the union strategy, which produces the phone numbers, and have the program pick select the set of duplicates for each phone number.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
with 
l as (
  select *, least(phone_main, phone_mobile, phone_tollfree) as p
  from t
)
select *
from l
where p in (select p from l group by p having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: I have to read the manual a bit for this one, (for least & with), but I will, and test it out, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to Common Table Expressions!  In this case I think the least() function will actually be problematic, since if any of the 3 columns is null it will return null, but I could use the with statement with @sabasabo's union query and get what I need.